# split string with specific character

Tags: sql, split, substring, charindex

Here is my situation
there is a column that comes from csv file, i loaded all fields properly in sql but in email column, i have more than 1 email address for some records.
if it would be 2 emails, i could handle but as long as i have 3-4 or more emails, then i have little problem.

here is an example 
'ekuntsche@addictionsuisse.ch;ekuntsche@suchtschweiz.ch;ekuntsche@sfa-ispa.ch;ekuntsche@addiction-info.ch'
this is only 1 column, i need to split them to 4 different column as email1,email2,email3,email4 and delimiter is ';'
I think i should use charindex and substring etc. but i could not create it. 
if someone can create a function and show how to run the function, that would be super helpful.
thank you
database name 'bi_deploy'
main column name is 'email'
unique id for this table is 'ID'
(this is only email table, every row will have 1 email address, i can make it actually, but i could not split emails properly)

Comment: You need to edit the question and add a tag for the specific database your using.

Comment: Strongly consider redesigning and having a table comprising an id and one email address per row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486172/what-is-the-best-way-to-separate-hyphen-delimited-data-into-several-columns-in-s/28486571#28486571

Comment: @Hagi, tag your question properly!

Comment: Actually it worked that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to separate hyphen-delimited data into several columns in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486172/what-is-the-best-way-to-separate-hyphen-delimited-data-into-several-columns-in-s)